# PHP: Store file until session expires

Tags: php, file-upload

For a client I am building a multi-step form in PHP5. On one of the first pages there are multiple file uploads. The uploaded files must be stored in a temporary directory until the user completes the form. At the moment all form data will be temporally saved in a Session with an unique number. I thought of storing the files in a session, but this will probably cause errors because an maximal size error.

Another method I thought about was to store the files in the temporary directory(tmpname()). But the problem of this method is that the temporary folder can be cleared by the os at any time. When that happens the files are lost.

The ideal solution would be that when the form is complete the files are moved to their permanent directory(this is not hard to do). And when the session is expired due to inactivity the files are removed from their temporally directory(to reduce unused space).

What would be the best way to make this? I.e. are there build-in features etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, why not store the names tempnam() generated in the session together with the intended file name? Like

```
$_SESSION['temp_files'] = array($truename => $tempname);
```

In the session_close you would manually unlink the files and be done. To prevent temp files from expired sessions to heap up in your temp dir you can have a job purge files with a certain age from the directory.

Did I forget anything?